# SQL - Time Between Each Task Update

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to calculate the time between each task update for the same activity id.  For example

```
  ActivityID 1 Task 1 = Started,    Audit Event Time = Date/Time    
  ActivityID 1 Task 2 = In progress, Audit Event Time = Date/Time 
  ActivityID 1 Task 3 = Complete, Audit Event Time = Date/Time 
  ActivityID 2 Task 1 = Started,    Audit Event Time = Date/Time
  ActivityID 2 Task 2 = In progress, Audit Event Time = Date/Time 
  ActivityID 2 Task 3 = Complete, Audit Event Time = Date/Time
```

etc.
What would be the proper sql code to subtract for activity Id 1, task 1 from 2 and 2 from 3, then do the same for activity id 2 etc?

The below query retrieves the sample data needed without the calculation.

SQL Query

```
 SELECT a.Subject, a.ActivityId, a.ActivityCategory, a.TaskStatusID AS TaskStatus, 
 a.AuditEventTime, t.TaskStatusID, t.TaskStatusName, p.ActivityID AS ActivityNum, 
 p.PortfolioID, b.PortfolioBaseID, b.CustodianBank
 FROM advapp.vActivity_Hist2 a
 JOIN APXUser.vTaskStatus t ON t.TaskStatusID = a.TaskStatusID
 LEFT JOIN AdvApp.vActivityPortfolio p ON p.ActivityID = a.ActivityID
 LEFT JOIN AdvApp.vPortfoliobaseCustom b ON b.PortfolioBaseID = p.PortfolioID
 Where ActivityCategory = 'Wire Transfers'  
 AND StartDate > Convert(date,'2022-07-01')
 Order by ActivityID Asc, TaskStatus
```

Sample Output
[Screenshot of output]

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you provide somthing in an online SQL fiddle to work out with?
And what version of MySQL are you using>

Answer (score 0):

you can use `lag`, and to incorporate it to your query:

```
 SELECT a.Subject, a.ActivityId, a.ActivityCategory, 
        a.TaskStatusID AS TaskStatus, a.AuditEventTime,
        t.TaskStatusID, t.TaskStatusName, p.ActivityID AS ActivityNum,
        p.PortfolioID, b.PortfolioBaseID, b.CustodianBank,
        datediff(a.AuditEventTime,lag(a.AuditEventTime,1,a.AuditEventTime) over (partition by a.ActivityId order by a.AuditEventTime)) AS EventGap
 FROM advapp.vActivity_Hist2 a
 JOIN APXUser.vTaskStatus t ON t.TaskStatusID = a.TaskStatusID
 LEFT JOIN AdvApp.vActivityPortfolio p ON p.ActivityID = a.ActivityID
 LEFT JOIN AdvApp.vPortfoliobaseCustom b ON b.PortfolioBaseID = p.PortfolioID
 Where ActivityCategory = 'Wire Transfers'  
 AND StartDate > Convert(date,'2022-07-01')
 Order by ActivityID Asc, TaskStatus
```

Comment: Thanks I will give it a shot.  Appreciate it.